# How to Stop Or Kill Or Terminate a Single Thread in ExecutorService or Job runs in the Thread?

Tags: java, threadpool, quartz-scheduler

a. How to Stop Or Kill Or Terminate a Single Thread in `ExecutorService` ?

b. How to Stop Or Kill Or Terminate the `Job` which is running in `ExecutorService` instead of the 
   Thread which is holding the job?

Thanks,
Kathir

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also tracked the thread via socket programming.

Assume a call has been initiated from web app to third party application.

Initiating the request via a thread using socket programming

Whenever user wants to kill the thread, we can do it in socket programming as it holds the exact thread.

In Quartz there is no way we can kill a running thread.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you are doing in you job ( = in your `Runnable` / `Callable` -implementation). If you are processing a list of items, you could check for a cancel-flag in between (which should be declared as volatile).

You could also use cancel(true) on your future object (when you are submitting a callable), but this as well would require that you test for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` inside your job.

Comment: or since canceling a `Future` issues an interrupt on the thread, the thread can just check its interrupted flag instead of using a volatile variable.

Comment: what cancel(true) actually does. will it kill the thread (or) kill the job (or) interrupt the job ?. could you please explain in detail.

Comment: `Future.cancel(true)` calls `Thread.interrupt()` on the thread of the job. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt() for the implications.